# Dual Booting With Windows 10 not working

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

We installed ubuntu linux in windows 10 machine. However, we are not getting dual booting option to run ubuntu after rebooting the laptop. After rebooting, windows 10 always shows up, never ubuntu linux. Please help us to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you know what you did during the Ubuntu setup? Please tell us what you did in each step of the Ubuntu installation

Comment: Go into BIOS and make sure that ubuntu is the first boot option.

Comment: Was Windows 10 pre-installed, so UEFI? Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode? Can you boot Ubuntu from UEFI one time boot key (same key you used to boot installer)? What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Some require you to change boot order in UEFI settings. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu / Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your installation method?
If it was through an usb stick, what is your boot table system( depends on your bios version).
If it is an UEFI it's important to do the fallowing:
When u press F11 to boot from the flash drive (usb) make sure u select UEFL:USB.
Then proceed normally with your installation.
I highly recommend that u search more about the booting tables tybes.
Please make your research first before doing anything could damage your boot framware it's IMPORTANT!!!.